# Push datas into an object

Tags: jquery

I'd like to push datas into an object, in order to have dynamic datas to post via ajax.

Here is my non-working code:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
        var data = {
            test: 'test'
        }

        $j('.fancyajax').bind('click', function () {
                var myclass = '.' + $(this).attr("id");
                $j(myclass).each(function() {
                        data.push({$j(this).attr("name") : $j(this).val()});
                });
        });
        $j('.fancyajax').fancybox({
                ajax: {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: what is `$j(this).attr("name")`? I dont see declaration of `$j`. Maybe there is an mistake

Comment: `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.push()` is for arrays - for hashes you can just do:

```
data[{$j(this).attr("name")] = $j(this).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$j('.fancyajax').bind('click', function () {
    var myclass = '.' + $(this).attr("id");
    $j(myclass).each(function () {
        data[$j(this).attr("name")] = $j(this).val();
    });
});
```

In order to add some data to a javascript **objects** you need to do like:

```
data['new variable name'] = 'new variable';
```

Answer (score 1):

Push if for array, but data is an object, so this should work:

```
$j(myclass).each(function() {
                        data[$j(this).attr("name")]  = $j(this).val();
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to;

```
data[$j(this).attr("name")]  = $j(this).val();
```